# Create css figure

Tags: css

How can i create css figure? I need something like on image.
May be online service, but i didn't find. It's a heavy figure, that's why I'm asking. Also, lateral colored figures I will need to change color.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa9q0.png)

Comment: have you tried anything yet ? if not , do and share it in the question so we can help where you fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, here is a example how you can reach the goal.

```css
button.figure {
    border: none;
    padding: 8px;
    color: #2F2F2F;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 10px / 50%;
    min-width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
button.figure:before,
button.figure:after {
    content: "";
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 10px/50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
button.figure:before {
    background: red;
    margin-left: -6px;
    left: 0;
}
button.figure:after {
    background: green;
    margin-right: -6px;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="figure">Button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You helped me)

Comment: a single class and much les CSS ;) : `.test {
  display:inline-block;
  background:#B2B2B2;
  padding:2em 4em;
  border-radius:2.25em/70%;
  box-shadow: 
    -0.75em 0 rgb(217, 89, 89), 
    0.75em 0 rgb(98, 217, 89)
}`